# installing ffmpeg on hosting that a person doesnt have full control of?+

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I am wanting to use ffmpeg on my site, but my hoster is infinityfree. It comes with Softalicious Apps Installer, but it doesn't have ffmpregg. Can I install it somehow? Can I get the binaries and copy them to a folder in the domain? Can I install it on WAMP, then copy the binaries over? (Install WAMP, install ffmpeg, then copy the binaries?). I don't use home hosting cause I only have 1 GB of free storage left, but with infinityfree, you get Unlimited.

Comment: What is the OS?

Comment: For infinityfree, unknown, and for my PC, Windows 7

Comment: Not much to work with here. So you could try to download a binary. See [FFmpeg Download](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html) page for links to builds for Windows, Linux, and macOS.

Comment: there's not nothing I can do right now... on work laptop (Windows RT where you can't install EXE apps, just a little Office 2013 workspace on a Surface 2)

Comment: I did check GitHub, but they didn't have binaries there for PHP

Comment: free hosts are not worth the money you pay, you can get a full vps for a few dollars a month

Comment: I don't make that much money though. only enough to live.

Comment: and to pay for my domain (I host a channel so I bought a domain on sale. I don't do monetization even though i'm eligible. I don't like people having to sit and wait just for me to get paid a few cents per view.)

Comment: https://forum.infinityfree.net/t/does-infinityfree-support-ffmpeg/10257 looks like you would be in trouble even if you could find a way, as they dont support hosting anything that would actually require the use of ffmpeg

Comment: This is a question for your hosting provider. Ask them, not us.

Answer (score 0):

Given your status, I would suggest getting an AWS account with their 12-month free tier offerings: https://aws.amazon.com/free

Launch a free Linux EC2 server, and put anything you want on it, including ffmpeg and WAMP. You can even put your database on a separate free server (up to 20gb). Then point your domain to it, and you’re set...at least for a year.